# How to get the number of characters in a one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm posting this question & answer because I've searched SO and haven't found a satisfactory answer for this problem and I hope this question & answer will help others in the future. Feel free to edit or add more *different* solutions to the ones I've included in my answer.

**This question is for *one-dimensional* arrays only.**

---

So let's say that I have this php array of strings:

```
$stringsArr = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'];
```

And I want to know how many total characters are in that array.

I *could* loop through the array and run a [`strlen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) on each element like this:

```
$stringsTotalLength = 0;
foreach ($stringsArr as $string) {
    $stringsTotalLength += strlen($string);
}
echo $stringsTotalLength; // Returns 22 correctly.
```

But I was wondering if there was any built-in php function or simple one-liner that could do this more elegantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a bunch of different ways to accomplish this, some more elegant, some less so. (Also, benchmarks on these solutions are welcome).

---

In 1st place, the winner is a combination of [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$stringsTotalLength = strlen(implode($stringsArr));
```

This works by concatenating all of the elements of the array and getting the length of that string, e.g. `['Lorem', 'ipsum']` -> `'Loremipsum'` -> `10`.

---

And in a close 2nd, there's a combination of [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), and [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php):

```
$stringsTotalLength = array_sum(array_map('strlen', $stringsArr));
```

This replaces the elements of the array with their lengths, and then gets the sum of the whole array, e.g. `['Lorem', 'ipsum']` -> `[5, 5]` -> `10`.

---

In 3rd place is the plain old foreach loop, though, while it is very simple, it is also kind of verbose:

```
$stringsTotalLength = 0;
foreach ($stringsArr as $string) {
    $stringsTotalLength += strlen($string);
}
```

---

Finally, in last place is a solution even worse than a foreach loop (IMHO), [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$stringsTotalLength = 0;
array_map(function ($string) {
    global $stringsTotalLength;
    $stringsTotalLength += strlen($string);
}, $stringsArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **implode** to change the array to string and count the length using  **strlen**

```
<?php

 $stringsArr = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'];

echo strlen(implode($stringsArr));  //22

?>
```